# Javafx Media Object path of file

Tags: java, javafx

I am using the latest version of javaFx. I want to play a simple mp4 file through javaFx but their is a problem with the path i guess, i am uploading the Exception and my code. please help me...

This is the code i am  working on:

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\mubas\\IdeaProjects\\Video_Player\\Vids\\Audio_Visulization.mp4");
        Player player = new Player();
        player.player(file.toURI().toString());
        player.mediaPlayer.play();

        try{
            BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
            root.setCenter(player);
            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();

        }catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}

class Player extends BorderPane {
    Media media;
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    MediaView mediaView;
    StackPane pane;

    public Player(){}

    public void player(String title)
    {
        media = new Media(title);
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
        mediaView = new MediaView(mediaPlayer);
        setCenter(mediaView);
    }
}
```

And this is the exception i am getting:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.2\bin\java.exe" --module-path "C:/Program Files/Java/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml --add-modules javafx.base,javafx.graphics --add-reads javafx.base=ALL-UNNAMED --add-reads javafx.graphics=ALL-UNNAMED "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.3\lib\idea_rt.jar=52674:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.3\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Users\mubas\IdeaProjects\MediaPlayerCheck\out\production\MediaPlayerCheck;C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib\src.zip;C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib\javafx-swt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib\javafx.web.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib\javafx.base.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib\javafx.fxml.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib\javafx.media.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib\javafx.swing.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib\javafx.controls.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib\javafx.graphics.jar" sample.Main
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.NativeMediaManager (in unnamed module @0x257c9660) cannot access class com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader (in module javafx.graphics) because module javafx.graphics does not export com.sun.glass.utils to unnamed module @0x257c9660
    at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.NativeMediaManager.lambda$new$0(NativeMediaManager.java:110)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:554)
    at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.NativeMediaManager.<init>(NativeMediaManager.java:107)
    at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.NativeMediaManager$NativeMediaManagerInitializer.<clinit>(NativeMediaManager.java:78)
    at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.NativeMediaManager.getDefaultInstance(NativeMediaManager.java:90)
    at com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaManager.canPlayProtocol(MediaManager.java:78)
    at com.sun.media.jfxmedia.locator.Locator.<init>(Locator.java:239)
    at javafx.scene.media.Media.<init>(Media.java:393)
    at sample.Player.player(Main.java:57)
    at sample.Main.start(Main.java:27)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application sample.Main

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I think the the problem is with the path of media. I googled it and try to solve it in many way but nothing is happens.

Comment: You've [asked this question already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60878036/javafx-media-object-path-of-file). It's still a duplicate. The problem, at least currently, has nothing to do with the path to the media. You're getting an `IllegalAccessError` that means the `javafx.media` module is not being used from the module-path. Wherever you define your VM arguments, make sure you have at least `--add-modules javafx.graphics,javafx.media`. If you end up using any controls do the same for `javafx.controls`.

Comment: OK now i get it, Thanks for helping the problem is solved now.   BTW i am new here and didn't know how the things go here so uploaded the pictures instead of code.